# Error While Publishing App

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, pngcrush

I got error that png files not found when I archive my app.

Error:

```
While reading /Users/AccountName/Desktop/update/App/App/top_bar.png pngcrush caught libpng error:
Not a PNG file..

Could not find file: /Users/AccountName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-erzlunhcqsjstvawfnqwjlhgtolx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/App.app/top_bar.png
Command /Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/copypng emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

Answer (score 0):

Your images have probably been run through Apple's "pngcrush" program and therefore are not valid PNG files any more.  I'm told that Apple's "pngcrush" has a way of reverting the damage and recreating a valid PNG from the crushed file, perhaps with some loss of data.  If you can look at the beginning of the file and the bytes "CgBI" appear starting at byte 12 instead of "IHDR", that will confirm that the file has indeed been apple-pngcrushed.

Comment: so what am I supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry, missed your second question.  I guess you are supposed to use Apple's "pngcrush" program, with its "-revert-iphone-compression" or some similar option (I don't have the code to check for sure) to undo the damage and recreate a valid PNG file (although there will be some unavoidable loss in any pixels that have alpha and were not black in the original).

Comment: can you put more light on that pngcrush program..can i use that program to compress image to send server in my application??

Comment: @vivek: There's some information here.  The real "pngcrush" doesn't have the "-revert-iphone-optiimizations" option; you must use the Apple-Xcode version of pngcrush which is somewhere in the Xcode SDK (I don't have access to it).See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1681/_index.html